# React Native RazorPay android Undefined|Undefined showing on click payment Button

Tags: react-native, razorpay

I am integrating Razor payment gateway in React native for android but on click of payment button always getting undefined|undefined. I am using `react-native-razorpay` library and did manual linking for android. Please help me to solve this issue.

Here is my code-

```
 _onPressButton() {
var options = {
    description: 'Credits towards consultation',
    image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png',
    currency: 'INR',
    key: 'Your razorpay key',
    amount: '5000',
    name: 'foo',
    prefill: {
      email: 'void@razorpay.com',
      contact: '9191919191',
      name: 'Razorpay Software'
    },
    theme: {color: '#F37254'}
  }
    RazorpayCheckout.open(options).then((data) => {
    // handle success
    alert(`Success: ${data.razorpay_payment_id}`);
  }).catch((error) => {
    // handle failure
    alert(`Error: ${error.code} | ${error.description}`);
  });
  }
```